# http 400 error uploading file to blobstore with google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, servlets, io

I'm trying to upload a file with the google app engine blobstore.

It's supposed to work like this: you call the BlobstoreService to get an upload url, supplying a callback URL.  The client is redirected to the upload URL, sends the data, then when they've finished they will be redirected to the callback URL with a couple of parameters which represent the blobstore key.

The dev server behaves differently to the production server as we shall see.

Against production, my code gets as far as completing the upload, then instead of getting a redirect back to my callback URL, I get a 400 error response (implying something wrong with my request).  How do I debug this in production?  I don't know how to switch on logging for the blobstore.

So I tried to run it locally against the dev server.  This time if I don't set the 'content-length' property, I get a 411 (content length not set).  But if I try and set that property, I get 'IllegalStateException: Already connected'.  Neither of these exceptions happen against production.

So I don't know where to go next.  I need to either get it working against dev, in the hope that I can debug the blobstore locally, or work out why it's not working on the blobstore in production.

```
    public void upload(String uri, File file) throws IOException    {
    HttpURLConnection conn=null;
    HttpURLConnection conn2=null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    DataOutputStream dos=null;
    try {
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "*****";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        URL url = new URL(uri);

        // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
//          conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(1024);
        conn.setRequestProperty("content-length", String.valueOf(file.length()));   //caused IllegalStateException "Already connected" locally, but not remotely

        log("Orignal URL: " + conn.getURL());
        //conn.connect();   //TODO duplicates url.openConnection() above?
        conn.getInputStream();  //so we can follow the redirect
        String redirectedUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");
        log("Redirected URL: " + redirectedUrl);
        //this is horrible and messy but let's get it working then clean it up later

        conn.disconnect();
        url = new URL(redirectedUrl);

        // Open a new HTTP  connection to  the URL
        conn2 = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn2.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn2.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn2.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn2.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn2.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn2.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn2.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
        conn2.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
        conn2.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize);
        conn2.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        conn2.connect();
        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn2.getOutputStream());

        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\""+file.getName()+"\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        // create a buffer of  maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize); 

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  
        }

        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        // Responses from the server (code and message)
        int serverResponseCode = conn2.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn2.getResponseMessage();
        //we are expecting another redirect here
        log("aaaargh! 400 instead of 302! "+serverResponseCode+" to "+conn2.getHeaderField("Location"));
    }catch (IOException e)  {
        log(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        log(e.getMessage());
        throw new IOException(e);
    }   finally {
        //close the streams //
        if (dos!=null)  {   
            try {
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){}
        }
        if (fileInputStream!=null)
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){}

        if (conn!=null )
            try {
                conn.disconnect();
            }catch(Exception ioe){}

        if (conn2!=null)
            try {
                conn2.disconnect();
            }catch(Exception ioe){}

    }
}
```

NB the serverResponseMessage string above comes back from the production blobstore as "Bad Request"

Comment: As you have said: you provide an upload URL to the client and then receive a simple callback. What is this code for?

Comment: I'm trying to upload a file from an android client, using the google app engine blobstore.

Comment: I suspect that you are actually not handling the exact name-value pair parameter to your backend servlet or controller. Hence you are getting this issue. Also check if you file is uploaded to blobstore or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using higher-level APIs rather than the low-level HttpConnection code I was attempting it with.

```
    public String uploadFile(String url, File f) throws Exception   {
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();    
    String str = "";
    HttpPost first = new HttpPost(url);  //a GET should work but I was getting 405
    HttpResponse firstResponse = httpClient.execute(first);
    str = firstResponse.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();
    //Post image to generated url
    HttpPost second = new HttpPost(str);
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(f);
    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
    second.setEntity(reqEntity);
    httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse secondResponse = httpClient.execute(second); 
    str = secondResponse.getFirstHeader("Location").getValue();
    log(str);
    return str;
}
```

This method returns the serving URL for the uploaded image.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it from an Android client, but I can show you how we did it from a javascript client as it **might** give you some pointers.

Client side is quite simple (this is an angular.js controller), we get the url to use and upload to it

```
// model file upload
    $scope.onFileSelect = function ($files) {
        $scope.uploadStatus = 'loading';
        for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
            var file = $files[i];
            console.log(file);

            $http.get('/endpoints/prototype/' + $scope.prototype.key + '/file/url')
                .success((function (data) {
                        console.log(data);

                        $scope.upload = $upload.upload({
                            url: data,
                            withCredentials: true,
                            file: file
                        })
                        .success(function (data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            $scope.prototype.modelFile = data;
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status) {
                            console.error(data);
                            $scope.uploadStatus = 'error';
                            $scope.uploadError = status;
                        });
                }))
                .error((function (data, status) {
                    console.error(data);
                    $scope.uploadStatus = 'error';
                    $scope.uploadError = status;
                }));
        }
    };
```

Server side, we have the endpoint which returns the URL to use for the post (this is a Spring MVC controller). Note that we specify the success path in createUploadUrl()

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoints/prototype/{key}/file/url", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String getFileUploadUrl(@PathVariable("key") String prototypeKey) {
    final UploadOptions uploadOptions = Builder.withDefaults()
          .googleStorageBucketName("palmyra-prototype-store");

    return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/endpoints/prototype/" + prototypeKey + "/file", uploadOptions);
}
```

Finally, the endpoint invoked after the upload is succeesful

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoints/prototype/{key}/file", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String handleFileUpload(@PathVariable("key") String prototypeKey, HttpServletRequest request) {
    final Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(request);
    final Map<String, List<FileInfo>> allFileInfos = blobstoreService.getFileInfos(request);

    final List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get(INPUT_FILE_NAME);
    final List<FileInfo> fileInfos = allFileInfos.get(INPUT_FILE_NAME);

    if ((blobKeys == null) || (fileInfos == null)) {
        return "You failed to upload a model file for " + prototypeKey + " because the file was empty.";
    } else if ((blobKeys.size() == 1) && (fileInfos.size() == 1)) {
        final BlobKey blobKey = blobKeys.get(0);
        final FileInfo fileInfo = fileInfos.get(0);

        final Prototype prototype = prototypeService.findByKey(prototypeKey);
        prototype.setModelFile(blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey).getFilename());
        prototype.setUploadedModelFile(fileInfo.getGsObjectName());

        prototypeService.updatePrototype(prototypeKey, prototype);

        return blobInfoFactory.loadBlobInfo(blobKey).getFilename();
    } else {
        return "One and only one file is allowed to be uploaded. The related prototype is " + prototypeKey +
              ". The number of blobs is " + blobKeys.size() + ", the number of files is " + fileInfos.size();
    }
}
```

That's it, hopefully it can help you with your issue.